# NullPointerException in TomcatResources with Springboot

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-boot, nullpointerexception

I want to write some JUnit integrationtests with springboot. My problem now is that I cannot get springboot to work since I get a NullPointerException

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
     at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatResources$Tomcat7Resources.addJar(TomcatResources.java:112)
```

I did some debugging and I found the following problems:

1. spring boot uses tomcat 8.5.23 on my test which is okay. But the code is loading a Tomcat7Resources instance in this code block:

   ```
   /**
    * Return a {@link TomcatResources} instance for the currently running Tomcat version.
    * @param context the tomcat context
    * @return a {@link TomcatResources} instance.
    */
    public static TomcatResources get(Context context) {
      if (ClassUtils.isPresent("org.apache.catalina.deploy.ErrorPage", null)) {
       return new Tomcat7Resources(context);
      }
      return new Tomcat8Resources(context);
    }
   ```
2. as a result the variable "***this.addResourceJarUrlMethod***" in the Tomcat7Resources instance becomes null because the reflection call cannot find the method that would obiously only be available with Tomcat8Resources.

   ```
   this.addResourceJarUrlMethod = ReflectionUtils.findMethod(context.getClass(),
               "addResourceJarUrl", URL.class);
   ```

   therefore the NullPointerException occuring a little bit later.

What can I do to prevent springboot to load the Tomcat7Resources?

Comment: It seems code finds Tomcat7 classes in your classpath too. Check your dependencies graph and find out what is loading it into your classpath.

Comment: that was fast :-) exactly this was the problem. For some unknown reason I had a transitive dependency to jbossweb in my classpath. I excluded it and now everything is fine